# Retrieving BLOB Data from MySQL Database

Tags: blobs

I am trying the following simple code.query is working but showing data of BLOB field unusual. How can I fix it?

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo$row['hline'].$row['date'];
    print("<BR/>");

    echo$row['details'];//blob field
}
```

proxy server2005-07-18 01:2

PK!Ýü•7f [Content_Types].xml ¢( ´TËnÂ0¼Wê?D¾V‰¡‡ªªú8¶H¥`ì
XõKöòúûnDUA*å)YïÌììÄƒÑÚšl   1iïJÖ/z,'½ÒnV²ÉK~Ï²„Â)a¼ƒ’m ±Ñðúj0ÙHu»T²9bxà<É9X‘
ÀQ¥òÑ
¤×8ãAÈO1~ÛëÝqé‚Ãk6$N{9›êÍ+P9Y ¢†vuÇGD²ìÃï»ÆoR€”wàÍ³¶
ÌIÊŠ~‰‰˜8›ïWòZè“"V0}¿˜ûßÀ»„´ù“>þÁŒýuQwHoî·áÿÿPK!‘·óN_rels/.rels ¢( Œ’ÛJA†ïßaÈ}7Û
"ÒÙÞH¡w"ë„™ìwÌ¤Ú¾½£ ºPÛ^æôçËOÖ›ƒ›Ô;§<¯aYÕ Ø›`Gßkxm·‹PYÈ[š‚g
GÎ°inoÖ/<‘”¡<Œ1«¢â³†A$>"f3°£\…È¾TºI S‘ÌõŒ«º¾ÇôWš™¦ÚY
igï@µÇX6_Ö]7~

Comment: The blob seems to be an open document format like .docx. You cannot just print that in html. What are you trying to do with the data?

Comment: I want to show the docx data of BLOB field from query in html format....

Comment: There _is_ no HTML format in that. It _is_ a Word file, which can be opened by Word or a compatible program.

Comment: when you indent text it will show up as code.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of data is your blob? If your blob is an image you need to base64_encode() before putting in your html. It will then looks like:
echo '';

Comment: You should use comments to ask questions.